# Is it necessary to use 'writeFragment' while updating cache after a mutation?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

So I am learning mutations from the apollo client docs and I came across updating the client cache after executing a mutation. Is it necessary to use writeFragment as described here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#making-all-other-cache-updates ?

Because I am able to do the same by spreading the existing array and adding the 'addTodo' object returned by the update function (this is how I do with redux at least)

my update functions looks like this:

```
update(cache, { data: { addTodo } }) {
      cache.modify({
        fields: {
          todos(existingTodos = []) {
            return [...existingTodos, addTodo];
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: necessary for the same reason - update other components dependent on the same data source (query result)

Comment: @xadm, yeah I understand the purpose behind using an update function. My question was about the use of fragment instead of spreading the array directly and adding the new object cause that worked just as well :)

Comment: cache mutation (subitems/subproperties) not always affects cache entry for entire query, components won't be rerendered ... writeQuery/writeFragment is for that

Comment: I am sorry for any confusion but they were re-rendering without any problems. Also the documentation says that the cache for the targeted field updates to whatever the return value we set for the modifier.

Please let me know if it'd help to share the sample code on codesandbox for you to have a look.

Comment: I belive it works, it's very basic use case ... in more complex it can fail ... just remember for future ... if some components with queries are not rerendered after mutations then check cache update methods.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess I will dive deep into fragments then :) Thanks @xadm

Answer (score 1):

> Like `writeQuery` and `writeFragment`, `modify` triggers a refresh of all active queries that depend on modified fields (unless you override this behavior).

> Unlike `writeQuery` and `writeFragment`, `modify` circumvents any merge functions you've defined, which means that fields are always overwritten with exactly the values you specify.

You can also add new fields with `writeFragment`.

```
client.writeFragment({
  id: '5',
  fragment: gql`
    fragment myTodo on Todo {
      completed
    }
  `,
  data: {
    completed: true,
  },
});
```

Reference: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#cachemodify
Reference: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6922